# How to display Oracle SQL Script Output via SAS SQL-pass-through facility?

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

**The Background:**

When I submit a SQL `MERGE` query via Oracle SQL Developer (e.g. to merge a transaction table `BUF_TRAN` into a base table `BUF_BASE`), it returns useful script output (in the Script Output window) such as `2 rows merged`, or `0 rows merged`, etc. It enables me to quickly get an idea of the size of data that got updated.

When I submit the same SQL query via SAS SQL-pass-through facility however, it ommits returning the script output.

**The Question:**

Is there a way to get SAS to write the oracle query script output as part of the SAS SQL-pass-through step?

**Sample codes (for simulation):**

*One-off*: Create table `BUF_BASE` and `BUF_TRAN` in Oracle. The tables look like this...

`BUF_BASE`

[image]

`BUF_TRAN`

[image]

Running the following PL/SQL in Oracle SQL Developer will create these tables in Oracle with data populated.

```sql
-- One-off: Create a base table and populate 1 row to it
DROP TABLE BUF_BASE;
CREATE TABLE BUF_BASE
  (
    NODE             VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    DATE_STAMP       VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PCT_USAGE        VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
    JOBRUN_DATE_TIME VARCHAR2(19) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT node_date_pk PRIMARY KEY (NODE, DATE_STAMP)
  ) ;
INSERT
INTO BUF_BASE
  (
    NODE,
    DATE_STAMP,
    PCT_USAGE,
    JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'A',
    '2015-01-01',
    '5',
    '2015-01-02T00:00:00'
  ) ;

-- One-off: Create the transaction table that has some rows to begin with.
DROP TABLE BUF_TRAN;
CREATE TABLE BUF_TRAN
  (
    NODE             VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    DATE_STAMP       VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PCT_USAGE        VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
    JOBRUN_DATE_TIME VARCHAR2(19) NOT NULL
  ) ;
INSERT
INTO BUF_TRAN
  (
    NODE,
    DATE_STAMP,
    PCT_USAGE,
    JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'A',
    '2015-01-01',
    '10',
    '2015-01-15T00:00:00'
  ) ;
INSERT
INTO BUF_TRAN
  (
    NODE,
    DATE_STAMP,
    PCT_USAGE,
    JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'A',
    '2015-01-02',
    '20',
    '2015-01-15T00:00:00'
  ) ;
commit;
```

Then run the following `MERGE` query in Oracle SQL Developer to update `BUF_BASE` using `BUF_TRAN`.

```sql
-- Merge transaction data into the base table
MERGE INTO BUF_BASE a USING BUF_TRAN b ON (a.NODE = b.NODE AND a.DATE_STAMP = b.DATE_STAMP)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET a.PCT_USAGE          = b.PCT_USAGE,
    a.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME     = b.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
  WHERE b.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME > a.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      NODE,
      DATE_STAMP,
      PCT_USAGE,
      JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
    )
    VALUES
    (
      b.NODE,
      b.DATE_STAMP,
      b.PCT_USAGE,
      b.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
    )
;
commit;
```

By running the above `MERGE` query, the Script Output window displays:

```
2 rows merged.
committed.
```

Run the `MERGE` query again and then it will say

```
0 rows merged.
committed.
```

Now, run the same `MERGE` query in SAS via the SQL-pass-through facility.

```sql
proc sql;
  connect to oracle (user=&BcoUser. password=&BcoPassword. path=&BcoPath.);
  execute (

MERGE INTO BUF_BASE a USING BUF_TRAN b ON (a.NODE = b.NODE AND a.DATE_STAMP = b.DATE_STAMP)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET a.PCT_USAGE          = b.PCT_USAGE,
    a.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME     = b.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
  WHERE b.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME > a.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      NODE,
      DATE_STAMP,
      PCT_USAGE,
      JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
    )
    VALUES
    (
      b.NODE,
      b.DATE_STAMP,
      b.PCT_USAGE,
      b.JOBRUN_DATE_TIME
    )

  ) by oracle;

  %put &SYSDBMSG.;
  %put &SYSDBRC.;

  execute (
     commit
  ) by oracle;

  %put &SYSDBMSG.;
  %put &SYSDBRC.;

  disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

The SAS log file simply returns the job run time (with error message 0). It does not however tell me how many rows got merged.

**The Question:**

Is there a way to get SAS to write the oracle query script output as part of the SAS SQL-pass-through step? e.g.

```
0 rows merged.
committed.
```

Comment: The script output messages are generated by the client, SQL Developer in this case; they can look slightly different in SQL*Plus, Toad or whatever, since they are not coming from the DB itself. The 'committed' message is essentially from the commit statement not erroring. The merged rows count is from SQL%ROWCOUNT, obtained from OCI or JDBC meta data; does SAS have a macro for that, or an equivalent? (I have no idea... just trying to clarify the question *8-)

Comment: SAS does have a sql rowcount; `&SQLOBS.`.  I'm not sure how that works with passthrough to Oracle though, and can't test.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001360983.htm has the six macro variables that might be useful, including `&SQLXMSG` and `&SQLXRC` which are pass-through specific - I would check one of those (or just `%put _all_;` and see if anything useful is in any macro variable).

Comment: It's worth noting that the `SASTRACE=` option can be enabled while using SQL Pass-through. This option will dump various amounts of information back to your SAS log from the database. Further information here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/a000433982.htm N.B. If you are doing operations that may generate large amounts of SQL statements (single-row inserts for example), then you may fill the SAS log.